# GitKraken commit ancestor order

Tags: gitkraken

Does GitKraken have a "sort commits by ancestor order" like SourceTree? The chronological sorting is useful for some use cases, the topological sorting is useful in a lot more circumstances. My team doesn't do rebase nor does it squash commits, precisely so we can keep the chronology straight, but it makes it a bit of a pain to visualize the branches.